# Where can I ask about example.com?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I recently discovered that some URL paths on [example.com](http://example.com/) cannot be used as valid URLs. Certain paths result in "*Encoding error*" or "*Site cannot be reached*"

- Valid: [`http://example.com/user_settings`](http://example.com/user_settings), [`http://example.com/login`](http://example.com/login), [`http://example.com/wp-admin`](http://example.com/wp-admin), [`http://example.com/xyz-stack-exchange`](http://example.com/xyz-stack-exchange)
- Encoding error: [`http://example.com/account_settings`](http://example.com/account_settings)
- Cannot be reached: [`http://example.com/user`](http://example.com/user), [`http://example.com/profile`](http://example.com/profile), [`http://example.com/admin`](http://example.com/admin), [`http://example.com/register`](http://example.com/register)

---

**I want to ask why "*account_settings*" would result in an encoding error.** I have considered:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/): Programmers use the site when testing APIs.
- [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/): It's *technically* a web app?
- [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/): Community would understand why certain paths would be invalid.

Is there a community where my question would be valid?

Comment: The domain is for **documentation**. Why do you expect *any* URL to work with it?

Comment: Not Web Applications.

Comment: Idle Curiosity Stack Exchange?

Comment: Probably nowhere, because no one could really tell you why. Only the domains themselves are reserved. Whatever web server IANA is running on them is unlikely to be documented anywhere outside the organization. It's very likely just slight modifications they've made over the years to tell bots to go away (e.g. every single path other than `/` *does* return the same page, just with a 404 status instead of a 200 - that seems like an obvious attempt to make bots stop hitting the page).

Comment: All of those URLs give me the same response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related to Stack Exchange and it is only for testing purposes.

- Web applications: **No** It is not a web application. It is a domain for testing purposes
- Web master: **No** because it is not something related to SEO or hosting or Marketing.
- Stack Overflow: **No** never

Then where you should ask?

The whois lookup shows that it is owned by IANA:

[image]

The only way you can get perfect help is to [contact IANA](https://www.iana.org/contact).

Comment: Webmasters has plenty of questions about [domains](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domains) (which the help also says is [on-topic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)); this would only be off-topic since it is about *another* site (questions there need to be about a site you control)

Comment: yes. questions about own domain are on-topic but this one I believe it's not on-topic